# @Html.DisplayNameFor not showing data MVC5

Tags: asp.net

I have searched around and not had much luck finding a solution to my exact problem.

**Model**

```
public class PageDetailsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Search(int SysID)
    {

      var query = from r in _db.Auctions
      from d in _db.Product_Details
      where SysID == d.Id && r.BidStatus == "Open" && d.Id == r.Product_DetailsId
      select new PageDetailsViewModel
      {                            
          Name = d.Name,
          Description = d.Description,
          Image = d.Image

      };
    return View(query);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectT.Models.PageDetailsViewModel>

@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name)
```

This fails to bring the name through. However, if I use a foreach

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
      @item.Name
}
```

It brings through the name no problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension method shows the value of the `DisplayNameAttribute` from DataAnnotations namespace. Consider this a label. Typically it is used like this:

```
[DisplayName("The Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

And in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name)                     <-- displays The Name
```

The code above will work only if the model is a single item. For the list case, as you have, you need to do some tricks, say a for loop, so you could do something like:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x[i].Name): @Model[i].Name <-- displays The Name: Bill
```

Comment: Adding [DisplayName] to my model and @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name) to my view did indeed bring back "The Name".

It just doesn't feel right looping though with @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x[i].Name): @Model[i].Name when i am only using 1 line of data you know.

Comment: @thewebnoob, what do you mean by "1 line of data"? Since you have typed your model with IEnumerable, the number of data items could be variable. If not, then you should really consider just `@model ProjectT.Models.PageDetailsViewModel`

Comment: Just a note, if you do not use getter and setter for an attribute, the display name will not display at all!